# MEAN Stack with Jade - app not defined - Controller not showing up in view

Tags: angularjs, express, controller, pug, mean-stack

I'm learning how to use the MEAN stack and having some issues with getting my jade view to use my controller.

Console logs show the app variable is not defined in my `animals-controller.js`. I did define it at one point by adding:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
```

before the .controller.. however it doesn't seem that my view is using my controller variables. in my li elements using ng-repeat. I included the controller as a script in my index.jade.  I'm assuming I need to reference the controller elsewhere as well? server.js?

![app not defined in animals-controller.js][1]

all code is in my gist below. however if you want to see the folder structure:

I have put up my code on my one drive:

http://1drv.ms/1CthhV1

https://gist.github.com/astemborskim/8b37fb1f919048671b5f.js"

I've spent hours looking for a solution to execute a separate controller in a MEAN stack with Jade.  Hopefully someone can see the issue.

Comment: While I'm still having trouble with getting my angular directives in my index.jade to render on the page from my external controller, I was able to fix my "app is undefined issue".  I was declaring the src to the controller before my app.js file. Once i switched the order the undefined error went away. however my view is still not rendering with the content from my controller.

Comment: I got it working! Comes down to a misplacement of the ng-app directive. I placed it on the head element in the index.jade file instead of the html element.